# VMWare Worksation hardware

Tags: vmware-workstation, hardware

I'm gonna spec a new computer, used for running VMWare Worksation. The computer will be running a few virtual machines - A dev machine running VS-2010, a build machine, a version-control machine, a web server for testing, a "personal" machine running office etc.

Any suggestions? Processor, MB, disks etc?

(P.S. The only item I AM sure of is that the machine will be using a Xonar Essence Stx, connected to my NAND amplifier ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i7/W35xx, as much memory as you can afford, Raid10 or 1, 64-bit OS - that's the best we'll be able to do without more into.

Comment: 1. Thanks :) 2. How would raid 1 help? 3. Raid 10 with four drives? 4. What more info?

Comment: VM performance hit is always IO, so any way to increase your IO performance will be a benefit.

Comment: when it comes to setting up your VM's don't allocate more memory than you need.  You may think, Server2008, that needs 1G or 1.5G.  That isn't necessary needed.  For small use, as in one user hitting a server, 512M or 786M may be plenty.  Just something to consider when setting up your VM's.  If you see that you are running out of memory on those machines, shut them down and allocate more.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have already purchased your new computer, but the following is what I have for my VMWare pc. I am able to run 2 or 3 VMs at 2GB each without any issues so far.

1. Memory 16GB - I would have liked 32GB but that was a bit expensive
2. OS Drive is a Samsung Evo 250GB SSD
3. VM Data Drives are 1TB Western Digital drives
4. CPU is an i7 4771
5. Mobo is an Asus Hero Maximus VI
6. Power Supply is a 600W
7. Case is a Cooler Master case with all of the fan slots used

Hopefully this helps you out, if you haven't already purchased.

BTW total price for that system was about $950 USD.

Comment: The question's 4 years old, chances are he's replace the computer he bought at the time

Comment: Of course I've already purchased a computer - am already thinking about the next one. Main takeaway: I'm using two SSDs of the VMs, and this really speeds them up. Also currently using 24GB RAM - usage does get as much as 17GB for three VMs.

Comment: cool, wish I had your hardware!